# Syncing with remote branch

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to push to remote branch directly ?

This is scenario:

There is branch on github repo lets call it X, I cloned project to my local repo, when i type:

```
git checkout origin/x
```

I get text in terminal saying: "You are in 'detached HEAD' state ...  If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create ... git checkout -b new_branch_name".

So i create new branch, do my job, make commit and push it to remote github repo with folowing command:

```
git push -u origin name_of_my_branch
```

That comand created branch on github repo, so now i am able to make pull request to that online branch, so again i am wondering is it possible to sync this branch directly with remote branch(x) and push to that branch(x) directly, without pull requests ?

Answer (score 0):

You can push directly to the remote branch:

```
git push -u origin x
```

Comment: I get error when i try to do so, more precise: 

    error: src refspect X does not match any.

Comment: Is the name of the remote branch `x`?

Comment: Yes name of the remote branch is X

Answer (score 0):

git will automatically track the local branch to the remote one if you just "git checkout x".  Don't prefix it with "origin/" or you will get the "detached head" message.